# AngularJS - ng-if check string empty value

Tags: angularjs

it's a simple example:

```
<a ng-if="item.photo == ''" href="#/details/{{item.id}}"><img src="/img.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
<a ng-if="item.photo != ''" href="#/details/{{item.id}}"><img ng-src="/{{item.photo}}" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

I see it always generates the `item.photo != ''` condition even if the value is empty. Why?

Comment: Do you mean it still has `ng-if="item.photo != ''"` attribute?

Comment: Unrelated, but this seems like a lot of duplication for just changing the image source.

Comment: Maybe `item.photo` is not an empty string, but `null` or `undefined`?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly use qualifiers like `item.photo == ''` or `item.photo != ''`. Like in JavaScript, an empty string will be evaluated as false.

Your views will be much cleaner and readable as well.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app init="item = {photo: ''}">
   <div ng-if="item.photo"> show if photo is not empty</div>
   <div ng-if="!item.photo"> show if photo is empty</div>
  
   <input type=text ng-model="item.photo" placeholder="photo" />
</div
```

*Updated to remove bug in Angular*

Comment: Although simple and clean, this answer hides a small bug in it, which might not matter to you so much. Just watch what happens when you enter one of: 0, n or f. I couldn't find any documentation about it or an open issue.

Comment: Yes -- this is an issue with older versions of AnguarJS (1.2.x and before). It exists in the version hosted on stackexchange. This bug has been fixed in 1.3.0 https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/bdfc9c02d021e08babfbc966a007c71b4946d69d

Answer (score 9):

Probably your `item.photo` is `undefined` if you don't have a photo attribute on item in the first place and thus `undefined != ''`. But if you'd put some code to show how you provide values to `item`, it would help.

PS: Sorry to post this as an answer (I rather think it's more of a comment), but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 7):

If by "empty" you mean `undefined`, it is the way ng-expressions are interpreted. Then, you could use :

```
<a ng-if="!item.photo" href="#/details/{{item.id}}"><img src="/img.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what may be happening, if the value of `item.photo` is undefined then `item.photo != ''` will always show as true. And if you think logically it actually makes sense, `item.photo` is not an empty string (so this condition comes true) since it is `undefined`.

Now for people who are trying to check if the value of input is empty or not in **Angular 6**, can go by this approach. 
Lets say this is the input field -

```html
<input type="number" id="myTextBox" name="myTextBox"
 [(ngModel)]="response.myTextBox"
            #myTextBox="ngModel">
```

To check if the field is empty or not this should be the script.

```html
<div *ngIf="!myTextBox.value" style="color:red;">
 Your field is empty
</div>
```

Do note the subtle difference between the above answer and this answer. I have added an additional attribute `.value` after my input name `myTextBox`. 
I don't know if the above answer worked for above version of Angular, but for **Angular 6** this is how it should be done.