# how to check a string is empty in angularjs

Tags: javascript

I am checking a value in my controller.Here is my code.

```
var contents = atob(response.documents);
// I checked the value in contents . it is displaying ""
if(contents === ""){
 // no contents
}
```

the if condition is retuning false, when the contents has "" and when the contents has data.
How to check condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - ng-if check string empty value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380000/angularjs-ng-if-check-string-empty-value)

Answer (score 19):

Good plain Javascript.

```
if(!contents){

}
```

Answer (score 11):

How about `contents.trim().length === 0` ?

Answer (score 1):

Empty string in Javascript is falsey you can use:

```
if(contents){
  //has content
}else{
 //no content
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In javascript "" is false and when you compare it with "", it **always** gives **true**.Maybe you have doubled empty string (empty string inside string)