# How to check for an empty string in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to check if a string is empty in a form, setting a default value if the answer is true, or passing the actual value if the string isn't empty.
Here's my code from the controller:

```
$scope.addElem = function () {
    $scope.lista2.push({
        com: null ? com = 'VUOTO' : com = $scope.newItem.com,
        gruppo: null ? gruppo = 'VUOTO' : gruppo = $scope.newItem.gruppo
    });
};
```

Here's the code from the HTML (I'm also using Bootstrap):

```
<form class="form-inline" name="input">
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-5" ng-model="newItem.com" placeholder="Nome del comico" ng-keypress="$event.keyCode == 13 && addElem()" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control col-5" ng-model="newItem.gruppo" placeholder="Gruppo del comico" ng-keypress="$event.keyCode == 13 && addElem()" />
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm col-2" type="submit" ng-click="addElem()">Inserisci</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is `newItem` defined in your controller?

Comment: Maybe this will help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869983/how-to-check-a-string-is-empty-in-angularjs/36870043

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380000/angularjs-ng-if-check-string-empty-value .

Comment: @wmash it is defined in the ng-model

Comment: @JoeRazon the first one gives me a suggestion from Visual studio saying it's expected ':' instead of '.';  the second one doesn't solve my problem since i don't want to show something in the page but to pass a value that has to be put in a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you were attempting to use ternary operators here to set the property of the object. The code below will set `com` to the value if `$scope.newItem.com` returns truthy or the default value of `"VUOTO"` if not. Same for `gruppo`.

```
$scope.lista2.push({
    com: $scope.newItem.com ? $scope.newItem.com : "VUOTO",
    gruppo: $scope.newItem.gruppo ? $scope.newItem.gruppo : "VUOTO",
});
```

Comment: i don't want to print (or in this case send to the table) `'VUOTO'` if the string isn't empty. I want to pass `'VUOTO'` if the string is empty, otherwise to pass the actual value of it

Comment: thank you very much, the solution works like a charm. so, in order to understand how it works, this code check if newItem.com has an actual value, if the condition is false it assigns the string VUOTO.Am I wrong?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, you are correct in that. An empty string in JS evaluates as falsy. So yes, if the string is empty, `"VUOTO"` will be assigned as the value. If you are unfamiliar with ternary operators, you can read about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: sorry to bother you, but this code des not recognize the string in `gruppo` field. if only `gruppo` has something, in the table i got `VUOTO-*blank*`, if both are empty i got `VUOTO-VUOTO` but if both are full i got `com's value-*blank`

Comment: So the error is that if the `<input>` field for `gruppo` is populated with a value *(string is not empty)*, that value is not in the table? What is the value you are putting into the `gruppo` field? Can you log `$scope.newItem.gruppo` and see that you have a value?

Comment: i typed some random letters to try. if you mean the html input code, is the question

Comment: Can you log (`console.log()`) `$scope.newItem.gruppo` to check what the value is?

Answer (score 2):

Your ternary condition is incorrectly built. Change it to something like below and it should work:

```
$scope.addElem = function () {
    $scope.lista2.push({
        com: $scope.newItem.com === null ? 'VUOTO' : $scope.newItem.com,
        gruppo: $scope.newItem.gruppo === null ? 'VUOTO' : $scope.newItem.gruppo
    });
};
```

Comment: now regardless of the content of the string in the table where these results are shown i got blank values

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/I59EE4M.png the last line "is born" after i tried to send the random letters to the table

Comment: Just replace `$scope.newItem.gruppo === null` with `$scope.newItem.gruppo.trim()` and `$scope.newItem.com === null` with `$scope.newItem.com.trim()` in that condition and try again

Comment: using `trim()` gives error if `com` has value but `gruppo` doesn't and sets `VUOTO-VUOTO` if both are full

Answer (score 0):

How about trimming data string?

```
$scope.addElem = function () {
  $scope.lista2.push({
    com: $scope.newItem.com.trim().length === 0 ? com = 'VUOTO' : com = 
  $scope.newItem.com,
    gruppo: $scope.newItem.gruppo.trim().length === 0 ? gruppo = 
    'VUOTO' : gruppo = $scope.newItem.gruppo
  });
};
```

Comment: with this solution if one of the input form is empty i got an Angular error